# How to short a push button switch to be always on

Tags: power, switches

I have a little bluetooth FM transmitter that uses a single button that you press and hold to turn the device on, press and hold to turn the device off, and press once to change the FM station it broadcasts to. Is there any simple way to alter a circuit like this to be "always on" and essentially short circuit the switch?

If it were some sort of toggle push button switch this would be simple, but seeing as it's a simple momentary push button used for other things, I have no idea where to even begin.

Comment: Are you wanting to modify it? If so do you have a link to the device?

Comment: It's just a little cheepie device I got off ebay. I want to modify it so it will be always on so if I disconnect then reconnect the battery I will not have to press the power button to turn it back on.

Comment: Link: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Bluetooth-V2-0-Wireless-Music-Receiver-FM-Radio-Transmitter-Black-/161080537203?pt=US_USB_Bluetooth_Adapters_Dongles&hash=item258125f073

Comment: What happens if the button is actually ALWAYS held down, does it power up and then just ignore it, or does it power on and then power off again? Have you actually tried it?

Comment: It powers up then ignores it

Comment: This question isn't clear. Yes, you can essentially short-circuit the switch by soldering a wire across it's leads. Is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a normally-closed pushbutton switch. When you apply power the unit will power up according to what you've indicated in the comments of your orignal question. The other actions invoked by the pushbutton might be edge-triggered and still work as intended.

Alternatively, connect a SPST toggle switch in parallel with the original N.O. push-button. Before you apply power to the device make sure the toggle switch is closed. Once powered up, open the toggle and use the PB switch as usual. Throw the toggle switch closed again to turn off the unit and leave it closed as you remove the power source. The toggle switch will then be ready for the next power application.